# Как отправить запрос в php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Имеется такой код:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     load_data();

     function load_data(query)
     {
      $.ajax({
       url:"fetch.php",
       method:"POST",
       data:{query:query},
       success:function(data)
       {
        $('#result').html(data);
        $("#result").html(data).selectpicker('refresh');
       }
      });
     }
     $('#date_groups').keyup(function(){
      var search = $(this).val();
      if(search != '')
      {
       load_data(search);
      }
      else
      {
       load_data();
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
```

Как сюда добавить отправку данных в fetch.php из выпадающего списка, который имеет название и id - freedom

Comment: Добрый вечер. Покажите html код

Comment: Тебе нужно занести данные в переменную query сделать $(" #freedom option:selected").val()  и отправить в функцию load_data( query ) по кнопке или при выборе